# php explode on a string containing chars like '\t' , '\0' etc

Tags: php

My code:

```
$string="655:47 Text: 0 n\some more text here\t\2\r\3\tl\0\f0\\f1\\f2\\a0\0\a1\0\a2\255";
$a=explode("\\",$string);
var_dump($a);
```

While the output i get is:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(33) "655:47 Text: 0 n"
  [1]=>
  stringl20) "some more text
0"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "f1"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "f2"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "a0"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "a1"
  [6]=>
  string(3) "a2­"
}
```

I want to split the string on every '\' chat found ( and yet retain all the values)
While I would like to have the function explode and to work correctly.
How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single-quotes instead of double quotes,

```
$string='655:47 Text: 0 n\some more text here\t\2\r\3\tl\0\f0\\f1\\f2\\a0\0\a1\0\a2\255';
$a=explode('\',$string);
var_dump($a);
```

In php, if you use single quotes then special characters like '/t' etc loose their meanings and behave as plain strings.

Comment: You need to use \\ and not \ :P

Comment: well please try to notcie single-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* working just fine.  You just aren't seeing all of the non-printable characters.

It isn't entirely clear whether or not you intend to have characters like `\n` or `\t` in your message, but when used within double quotes (`"`), you are escaping into special characters.  For example `"\t"` is a string that actually contains a tab character, and `\n` is a line feed.

If you don't want these characters, just change those double quotes to single quotes:

```
$string='655:47 Text: 0 n\some more text here\t\2\r\3\tl\0\f0\\f1\\f2\\a0\0\a1\0\a2\255';
```

If you do that, you'll get the following output:

```
array(17) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "655:47 Text: 0 n"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "some more text here"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "t"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "r"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [6]=>
  string(2) "tl"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [8]=>
  string(2) "f0"
  [9]=>
  string(2) "f1"
  [10]=>
  string(2) "f2"
  [11]=>
  string(2) "a0"
  [12]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [13]=>
  string(2) "a1"
  [14]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [15]=>
  string(2) "a2"
  [16]=>
  string(3) "255"
}
```

Comment: I used to think that in php both quates are same :P

Comment: @kritya, In PHP, they definitely have two distinct meanings.  In general, you should be using single quotes (`'`).  They are slightly faster, since PHP doesn't try to parse variables and what not in your string.  See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/3446216/362536